# How long for X basic operations to execute?

Tags: execution-time

How long for 10^9 basic operations to execute?

Firstly, how would try to solve how long this thing will execute?
Second, what if instead of 10^9 I am given a random Integer i.e.: (x^10) or (10^x) or (n^x)

Thank you!

Comment: How long to execute on what? A CPU? RISC or CISC? What architecture? A virtual machine?  An interpreter?  What kind of operations? Integer math? Floating point? Control instructions? A mix?  Is the clock speed fixed? What else is executing at the same time? Are you counting OS overhead? Are the operations executed in parallel or serially?

Comment: Hi there are no given information asides from the number of basic operations. I had the same question as you, as the computing power of a device does influence the time